# load static jspm resources to production index.html?

Tags: javascript, gulp, jspm, systemjs

Perhaps I am missing something, but here is my problem:
after running `gulp dist` to go on "production mode", all `javascript` files are bundled ok but in the index.html there are still references to `jspm_packages` folder and also to some of the JavaScript files as follows:

```
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap@3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
        <script src="config.js"></script> 
        <script>
             System.import('build/js/main.js!jsx');
        </script>
    </body>
```

all those references are no longer exists in dist folder, which is created in the `gulp dist` task.

Here is a use case example from one of React+JSPM projects on GitHub: https://github.com/tinkertrain/jspm-react

This behaviour is common to a many projects which I've encountered, so probably I am missing something...
Should I configure something to make some adjustments? maybe calling another task to create my own "production mode" html?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to process your html and replace all those `<link>` and `<script>` with the production ones. There are arguably many ways and tools to do it, but as you say you're using Gulp you might want to check [Gulp-html-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace).

Basically the idea is to add some html comments that instruct your chosen tool to replace those tags with the production ones. In your case

```
   <head>
    <!-- build:css -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap@3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/main.css"/>
   <!-- endbuild -->
   </head>

    <!-- build:js -->
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script> 
    <script>
         System.import('build/js/main.js!jsx');
    </script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Will produce:

```
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <script src="js/bundle.min.js"></script> 
  </body>
```